# Update Neo4j node labels via Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a clean way to replace a node's labels with a new list of labels?

You can replace properties with the Cypher below. Is there something similar for labels?

```
MERGE (n)
SET n = {foo: 42, bar: 69}
```

I am aware that you can set several labels with the below Cypher. This however does not remove labels that are not in the new list.

```
MERGE (n)
SET n:Foo:Bar
```

My code that executes the Cypher query gets a new list of labels and does not know what the old labels are.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no idea on the old labels to remove then you can collect all labels on that node and use the apoc function removeLabels to remove the labels.  Then assign new labels on this node.

```
// find nodes
MATCH (n:Person)
// get all labels attached to these nodes (except Person itself)
WITH n, [lbl in labels(n) WHERE lbl <> 'Person' | lbl] as lbls
// call apoc function removeLabels using the list of nodes and labels to remove
CALL apoc.create.removeLabels(n, lbls) YIELD node  
// assign new labels to these nodes
SET node:FOO:BAR
```

Comment: My code that executes the Cypher query gets a new list of labels and does not know what the old labels are. So I could use the Cypher you provided after looking up the labels with another Cypher query and then doing a diff. That is really unwieldy though.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your clarification. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apoc functions to add and remove labels when they are in a list:

```
create (t:Temp:Foo)
with ["Temper", "Tempest"] as newlabels
match (t:Temp)
with t, newlabels, labels(t) as oldlabels
call apoc.create.addLabels(t, newlabels)
yield node
with node as t, oldlabels
call apoc.create.removeLabels(t, oldlabels)
yield node
return node
```

That will create a new node with labels Test and Foo, add the labels Temper and Tempest, and remove the existing labels.

There is also:

```
match (t:Temp)
with collect(t) as mynodes
call apoc.refactor.rename.label("Temp", "Tempest", mynodes)
yield total
return total
```

That one does a 1-for-1 replacement of labels though, so it doesn't sound like what you are looking for.